# How to avoid including many indirect libraries in tests? (C/C++, binutils)

Tags: c, linker, binutils

If you have a test, which depends on an library in your code-base (static library in this case).

Say `testFoo` depends on a single function from `libBar`.

However other functions in `libBar` (that we don't use), call `libSpam` and `libSpaz`... in turn, they have their own dependencies.

This can get you into dependency hell, where you end up needing to link all libraries.

In practice I only found a few ways to handle this:

- Link (almost) everything
  *(Works but is slow for large programs).*
- Use *stubs*, a source file which has NOP functions for all the unused symbols which are needed to link, but only used indirectly by functions we don't call.
  *(Works, but a hassle to maintain, when there are 100's+).*
- Split up the libraries so they can be included for testing.
  *(It may not be acceptable to re-arrange the entire source-tree just so tests are faster to link).*
- Use ifdef's and compile the same source files into multiple libraries, one which doesn't contain references to the unneeded symbols.
  *(Works but is a hassle to maintain, especially if tests use different parts of the libraries)*.

Is there a way to tell the linker to *drop* or *ignore* some symbols/functions? so these kinds of workarounds aren't needed?

Or detect that some symbols are never used by the test and not give linking errors?

Comment: Interesting question. Usually, when I build unit tests in c, I build *small* tests that only focuses on 1 lib/app. The apps in turn are *small* apps, that only references 1 or 2 other libs. As the dependencies already are compiled, I haven't really noticed huge link times before. (And I do a lot of kernel work.) How about disabling all "link optimizations"? Gigantic output, but fast?

Comment: Right, everything's built, so its only the binary size and link time. Possibly its just because its a fairly large code-base, with debug builds the final binary is ~270+mb takes a few seconds to link, so not exactly slow. Also impractical if you want to have more then a few tests not fill up your SSD.

Comment: Maybe the unit tests could use shared object files instead. Many libs makes both anyway, so it might not need to affect the setup much. (Apps would need an extra output added to the makefiles.) That ought to delay the link for runtime?

Comment: Good point, while the binary is linked statically, theirs no reason the tests must be (could make a library for the purpose of tests only).